# Data in .txt to not overwrite

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am quite new to programming. I created a game and scene where I can select levels.... and I want to not load the level if the player has not won it. I made a script that creates file.txt at the start of the game with information it has not been won. After making it to the end there is another script that overwrites this file with information it was won.

And here is my problem: If I select level, that was already won, from my level selection. File with information about completing the level is overwritten again and if I just quit the game or level without completing it, the file stays like this and I cannot select it again because the game things I did not complete it.
To solve this problem I think that if I edit the script to not overwrite this file and just add a new lines to it everytime it is run and when I want to check if it has been won I just read all lines and if one of the lines contains information that level was completed I just let the button to load this level.

Is there some better way to do this?

I hope this is clear description because my English is not in the best shape :)

Comment: Check https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html, maybe you can cut the code and get the same result.

Comment: First of all, add your code. Second, if you have a concrete structure of data, then serialize it. Create per example a class named Config, add there as many values as you will need to use (booleans to determine if the levels are finished, integers for score and so on) then deserialize that class when the game begins and after each config change serialize it again to the file.

Comment: Creating your own file for this definitely seems like a smell, as per @bruce965 advice, take a look through the unity docs, there's bound to be somewhere you can store game data.